# Dates not sorted using Datatables

Tags: mysql, datatables

I am using Datatables in a web site to show MySQL records. My problem is that 
on first page load, the records are not shown as expected from the query.
Here you have the query, 'vigencia' is a field from type date, and the records are not sorted by descending date 'vigencia':

```
// Execute job
  if ($job == 'get_companies'){

    // Get companies
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_documentos LEFT JOIN tbl_uploads ON tb_documentos.id_doc = tbl_uploads.doc ORDER BY vigencia DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
    if (!$query){
      $result  = 'error';
      $message = 'query error';
    } else {
      $result  = 'success';
      $message = 'query success';
      while ($company = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        $imagen = "<a href='uploads/uploads/".$company['file']."''><img src='uploads/uploads/".$company['file']."' width='80' height='60'>";
        $mysql_data[] = array(

          "numero_identificador"  => $company['numero_identificador'],
          "serie"    => $company['serie'],
          "numero_documento"       => $company['numero_documento'],
          "tipo_documento"     => $company['tipo_documento'],
          "vigencia"     => $company['vigencia'],
          "archivo"  =>   $imagen
        );
      }
    }
```

And here the JS code:

```
 // On page load: datatable
  var table_companies = $('#table_companies').dataTable({
    "ajax": "data_vencimientos.php?job=get_companies",
    "columns": [

      { "data": "numero_identificador" },
      { "data": "serie" },
      { "data": "numero_documento" },
      { "data": "tipo_documento" },
      { "data": "vigencia", },
      { "data": "archivo" }
    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":       " ",
        "sPrevious":    " ",
        "sNext":        " ",
        "sLast":        " ",
      },
      "sLengthMenu":    "Documentos por pagina: _MENU_",
      "sInfo":          "Total de _TOTAL_ documentos (mostrando del _START_ al _END_)",
      "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtrados _MAX_ documentos)"
    }
  });
```

After the first page load, I can sort the records properly clicking on the column table header.

What should I change to show the records sorted by 'vigencia' (Date field from type YYYY-m-d, ex. 2016-08-12)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking deeper in the Datatables documentation, I have found that you can change the sorting order just including a parameter in the AJAX function, like this in my case:

"order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],

And it works now.

THank you.